# Transclude content of nested directive into the outer directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i want to create a new AngularJS directive (`outer-directive`) that wraps some content (e.g. html or other directives) and creates dynamically a small navigation on the left side.

I don't get this sample running. The `content-section` directive is just for grouping `content` directives in the left side menu and does not need any markup. The `content` directive should show it's transcluded content in the `outer-directive` placeholder only if active.

Anyone has an idea or hint on how to solve this problem with AngularjS 1.5?

Example in pseudo code:

```html
<outer-directive>
  <content-section heading="Section 1">
    <content heading="Content 1 in Section 1">
      <!-- some HTML or other directives, etc -->
    </content>
    <content heading="Content 2 in Section 1">
      <!-- some HTML or other directives, etc -->
    </content>
  </content-section>
  <content-section heading="Section 2">
    <content heading="Content 1 in Section 2">
      <!-- some HTML or other directives, etc -->
    </content>
  </content-section>
</outer-directive>
```

Directive template:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <!-- some kind of left side menu (want to use uib-accordion directive here) -->
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="contentSection in contentSections">
        <h3>{{contentSection.heading}}</h3>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="content in contentSection">
            <a href ng-click="showContent(content.$id)">{{content.heading}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <!-- show active content here with ng-if -->
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
  </div>
</div>
```

Directives pseudo code:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('outerDirective',
    [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: 'outer-template.html',
                controller: [
                    '$scope',
                    function($scope) {
                        $scope.contentSections = [];

                        this.addContentSection = function(contentSectionScope) {
                            var that = this;
                            $scope.contentSections.push(contentSectionScope);

                            contentSectionScope.$on('$destroy',
                                function(event) {
                                    that.removeContentSection(contentSectionScope);
                                });
                        };

                        this.removeContentSection = function(contentSectionScope) {
                            var index = $scope.contentSections.indexOf(contentSectionScope);
                            if (index !== -1) {
                                $scope.contentSections.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                        };
                      
                      // ...
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ])
    .directive('contentSection',
    [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                require: '^outerDirective',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                //template: '',
                scope: {
                    heading: '@'
                },
                controller: [
                    '$scope',
                    function($scope,) {
                        $scope.contents = [];

                        this.addContent = function (contentScope) {
                            var that = this;
                            $scope.contents.push(contentScope);

                            contentScope.$on('$destroy',
                                function (event) {
                                    that.removeContent(contentScope);
                                });
                        };

                        this.removeContent = function (contentScope) {
                            var index = $scope.contents.indexOf(contentScope);
                            if (index !== -1) {
                                $scope.contents.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                        };
                    }
                ],
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, outerCtrl) {
                    outerCtrl.addContentSection(scope);
                }
            }
        }
    ])
.directive('content',
    [
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                require: '^contentSection',
                transclude: true,
                template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
                scope: {
                    heading: '@'
                },
                controller: [
                    '$scope',
                    function ($scope) {
                        
                    }
                ],
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, contentSectionCtrl) {
                    contentSectionCtrl.addContent(scope);
                }
            }
        }
    ]);;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Angular UI's "Tabs" directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) [solves this problem.](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js)

In your case you would do something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Your HTML would be:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<uib-tabset template-url="custom-tabset-template.html">
  <uib-tab heading="Section 1">
    <!-- some HTML or other directives, etc -->
    Section 1 Content
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab heading="Section 2">
    <!-- some HTML or other directives, etc -->
    Section 2 Content
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab heading="Section 3">
    <!-- some HTML or other directives, etc -->
    Section 3 Content
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
</body>
```

And the custom-tabset-template.html would be:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- You can use uib-accordion directive here. In that case you would 
   have to replace the heading attr on the tab with a nested 
   uib-tab-heading element inside each tab -->
  <ul class="col-sm-3" ng-transclude></ul>
  <div class="col-sm-9 tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane"
      ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs"
      ng-class="{active: tabset.active === tab.index}"
      uib-tab-content-transclude="tab">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and [here is a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UCpMjS?p=preview).

Enjoy.